# OS Catalina. Apache server not working. Getting the message 'Could Not Find Specified Service' on Mac terminal

Tags: php, macos, apache, terminal

hopefully you can help me out! I've started running an apache web server from my computer but when I try to add html or php files to Library/WebServer/Documents to run on a localhost, the browser is saying 'this site cannot be reached'. I have tried restarting apache but nothing happens.

Another side note, I have tried to stop apache running with 'sudo apachectl stop' but this doesn't seem to work - the terminal is displaying the message '/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Couldn't find specified service' and the browser still displays the 'it works!' message. Some help please!